# context.read<T> or Provider.of<T>(context, listen: false) inside initState not working as expected

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I have read a lot of related questions/answers, but I still can't find the solution to my problem.

My code is simple. I have a `Provider` injected into the `Widget Tree`, as follows:

**Provider**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:unify_sports_web/core/utils/data/datasource/enums/utils_status_enum.dart';
import 'package:unify_sports_web/core/utils/data/models/load_image_request_model.dart';
import 'package:unify_sports_web/core/utils/domain/usecases/load_image_usecase.dart'
    as _params_load_image_usecase;
import 'package:unify_sports_web/core/utils/domain/usecases/load_image_usecase.dart';
import 'package:unify_sports_web/core/utils/utils.dart';

class UtilsProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final LoadImageUseCase _loadImageUseCase;
  UtilsState utilsState = UtilsState.initialState;

  UtilsProvider(this._loadImageUseCase);

  Future<Image?> loadimage(String name) async {
    utilsState = UtilsState.loadImageSendState;
    notifyListeners();

    final resp = await _loadImageUseCase(_params_load_image_usecase.Params(
        request: (LoadImageRequestModel(name: name))));

    return resp.fold((l) {
      Utils().showException(message: l.message);
      utilsState = UtilsState.loadImageErrorState;
      notifyListeners();
      return null;
    }, (r) {
      utilsState = UtilsState.loadImageSuccessState;
      notifyListeners();
      return r.image;
    });
  }
}
```

**In an ancestor parent**

```
ChangeNotifierProvider(
          lazy: false,
          create: (_) => UtilsProvider(
            Injector.instance!.getDependency(),
          ),
        ),
```

I want to show a photo but I have to download it first, so I use my `UtilsProvider`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:unify_sports_web/core/utils/providers/utils_provider.dart';

class PlayerAvatar extends StatefulWidget {
  const PlayerAvatar({
    Key? key,
    this.image,
    this.showShadow = false,
    this.borderColor = Colors.black,
    this.borderWidth = 1,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String? image;
  final bool showShadow;
  final Color borderColor;
  final double borderWidth;

  @override
  State<PlayerAvatar> createState() => _PlayerAvatarState();
}

class _PlayerAvatarState extends State<PlayerAvatar> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    context.read<UtilsProvider>().loadimage(widget.image!).then(
      (value) {
        if (mounted) {
          setState(
            () {
              imageToShow = value;
            },
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }

  Image? imageToShow;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 64,
      height: 64,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        border: Border.all(
          color: widget.borderColor,
          width: widget.showShadow ? 2 : widget.borderWidth,
        ),
        boxShadow: widget.showShadow
            ? [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.25),
                  blurRadius: 4,
                  offset: const Offset(0, 4),
                )
              ]
            : [],
      ),
      child: (widget.image == null || widget.image == '' || imageToShow == null)
          ? const Icon(
              Icons.person_outline,
              size: 36,
              color: Colors.black,
            )
          : ClipOval(
              child: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 64,
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                backgroundImage: imageToShow!.image,
              ),
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

According to the documentation, `context.read<UtilsProvider>` is the same as `Provider.of<UtilsProvider>(context, listen: false)`. But in both cases I get the error:

```
════════ Exception caught by foundation library ════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while dispatching notifications for UtilsProvider:
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
```

Why is the `Widget` marked as needing to be reBuilt, if `listen` is `false`? I expected the function `notifyListeners()` call to have no effect on the state of `PlayerAvatar` because `listen` is `false`. What am I doing wrong? Please help.

**NOTE**
I understand that I don't use the `UtilsProvider` variables at all, and therefore I don't need to call the `notifyListeners()` function, but in the future I will.

Comment: `initState` is not a good place to call async function. I think this happens: `initState` runs and starts the future, the first build starts while the future is running, and the future completes before the first build is finished. Therefore the `setState` runs while the first build is in progress and that throws the error.

Comment: You could try in `initState`: `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {context.read...});`

Comment: Are you saying that initState finishes, and the first build starts, before the future finishes, and then the future completes before the first build finishes?

Comment: Yes, that's my guess. I had similar problems. Best thing is to avoid async in `initState` and user a `FutureBuilder`, `StreamBuilder` etc. You can't use `await` in `initState`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your code inside the addPostFrameCallback in the initState, which will bind the data to the provider's variable once the widget building is completed,

```
 WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    
      //Add the code here
    
    });
```

so your code will be like

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {


 context.read<UtilsProvider>().loadimage(widget.image!).then(
      (value) {
        if (mounted) {
          setState(
            () {
              imageToShow = value;
            },
          );
        }
      },
    ); 
});
```